# SceneKit/ARKit floor reflections reflectionCategoryBitMask

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I need to have a floor in the `scene` which will reflect only some objects, not all. I have created a `floor` in such a way:

```
let floor = SCNFloor()
floor.firstMaterial!.lightingModel        = .constant
floor.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents     = UIColor.clear
floor.firstMaterial!.writesToDepthBuffer  = true
floor.firstMaterial!.readsFromDepthBuffer = true
floor.reflectionCategoryBitMask = 4
```

reflections are shows correctly, but for all objects. Even if I have a node with category bit mask = 1. Why is that? Documentation for reflectionCategoryBitMask states:

> A mask that defines which categories of other objects show reflections
>   on the floor.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This might help: https://medium.com/bpxl-craft/working-with-3d-models-in-scenekit-c5e75a958f9f eg: to assign a category properly, you must use only powers of 2: 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

Comment: I do, Here I just placed 4 for simplicity, but in real code I use 1 << 1, 1 << 2, 1 << 3, etc, so I get 2, 4, 8 ...
And it does work for lights, just not for reflections on the floor

Comment: @DamianDudycz Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, sorry. I ditched this functionality